# Default Exception Response Codes in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Not sure if I'm asking the right question here but, does .NET have default response codes for specific errors? if so, what response code does it return for concurrent DB update exceptions when it goes unhandled in application code?

Comment: You tagged this question with [tag:asp.net] and you ask about response codes. Are you asking about HTTP response codes? In most cases of an unhandled exception, the response code would be 500.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that .Net doesn't have default response *codes*. There are many *types of Exceptions* that are thrown in certain situations.e.g NullReferenceException.

The exception returned by a DB update exception will depend on the library used to access the data. For instance I  think Entity Framework throws a DbUpdateConcurrencyException. Linq-To-Sql library throws a ChangeConflictException.

If you aren't using an ORM then likely you will get a [SqlException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx) that has a number that relates to the underlying provider's (e.g. Sql Server) Result Code.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

The "response code" of each .NET exception is the responsibility of the code that throws it.

There are two main ways in which client code can convey exception "codes" to client code:

- using the [HRESULT property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult) of the `Exception`type or
- [inheriting from the `Exception` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and providing a more specialized
  exception type.

Depending on the exception types you're handling, you can either look into the HRESULT value (used to communicate exception details between managed and unmanaged code), or employ the exception handling pattern that .NET imposes by requiring that all specialized exceptions inherit from `Exception` (i.e. catching exceptions in order, starting with from most specialized exceptions.)

In the case of database exceptions, for example, the more-specialized exception types could provide additional "code" information - as is the case with SqlException.Number, which probably maps to underlying SQL server Error Codes - the default ones come from this table:

```
use master
select * from sysmessages
```

There are resources online which attempt to consolidate all known specialized Exception types, for example: https://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/net-exceptions-all-of-them/